# Complex cypher queries with mathematical formula

Tags: neo4j, similarity, graph-databases, cypher

I have a graph with 2 kinds of nodes: `person` & `food`. I have 1 kind of relationship - `Ate` with an attribute - `count`. Each time a `person` *eats* a `food`, the `count` attribute of the relationship gets incremented.

My goal is to calculate similarity between two `person` nodes. I found this algorithm online to calculate the similarity and I want to use it. How does one convert this to a Cypher Query ?

```
sim = 0
for k = 1 to n:
  sim = sim + (1 - Math.abs((N1k/H1 - N2k/H2)))(N1k+N2k)/(H1+H2)
```

where:

sim = similarity index 
H1 = total number of `food` items eaten by `person` 1 
H2 = total number of `food` items eaten by `person` 2 
n = number of `food` nodes in **common** 
N1k = number of times `person` 1 has eaten 'kth' `food` item out of the 'n' common `food` items 
N2k = number of times `person` 2 has eaten 'kth' `food` item out of the 'n' common `food` items

I have the skeleton ready but I just don't know how proceed.

```
Start me=node(name="%s")
MATCH me-[r1:Ate]->some_food<-[r2:Ate]-other_dude
// do some stuff here to find out sim
RETURN other_dude, sim
ORDER BY sim DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Help appreciated !

Comment: I'm trying to write your query, but I need to understand this:
"N1k = number of times person 1 has eaten 'kth' food item out of the 'n' common food items". What does kth mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw this question on Neo4j mailing list, but couldn't respond yesterday.

I'm a newbie when it comes to Cypher. However, I could help you with a solution to your problem in Gremlin. I could create a graph similar to yours and ran a Gremlin traversal on it.

My Graph looks like:

```
gremlin> g.v(1,2,3,4)_().outE('eats').inV.path{it.name}{it.count}{it.name}  
==>[Neo, 5, Meat]
==>[Neo, 1, Cheese]
==>[Neo, 4, Chicken]
==>[Morpheus, 3, Bread]
==>[Morpheus, 3, Cheese]
==>[Morpheus, 2, Chicken]
==>[Trinity, 1, Apple]
==>[Trinity, 2, Bread]
==>[Trinity, 4, Meat]
==>[Trinity, 2, Cheese]
==>[Smith, 3, Apple]
==>[Smith, 4, Ham]
==>[Smith, 5, Pork]
gremlin>
```

I wrote a traversal to generate similarity indices for any one vertex, indicated by `start` against an array of remaining IDs. My final traversal looks like:

```
simarray=[];start=3;
[1,2,4].each{
                p1=start;p2=it;
                first=g.v(p1);
                second=g.v(p2);
                sim=0;
                h1=first.out('eats').count().toFloat();
                h2=second.out('eats').count().toFloat();
                first.outE('eats').as('edges')
                .inV.in('eats').has('id',second.id).back('edges')
                .each{
                        n1k = it.count;
                        n2k = it.inV.inE('eats').outV
                                .has('id', second.id).back(2).count.next();
                        sim = sim + (1 - ((n1k/h1)-(n2k/h2)).abs())*(n1k+n2k)/(h1+h2)
                        };
                simarray.add(sim)
            };
simarray
```

Output:

```
gremlin> simarray=[];start=3;[1,2,4].each{p1=start;p2=it; first=g.v(p1); second=g.v(p2); sim=0; h1=first.out('eats').count().toFloat(); h2=second.out('eats').count().toFloat(); first.outE('eats').as('edges').inV.in('eats').has('id',second.id).back('edges').each{n1k = it.count; n2k = it.inV.inE('eats').outV.has('id', second.id).back(2).count.next(); sim = sim + (1 - ((n1k/h1)-(n2k/h2)).abs())*(n1k+n2k)/(h1+h2)}; simarray.add(sim)};simarray
==>0.7857142857142856
==>0.7142857142857143
==>0.14285714285714285
```

Above traversal directly translates to your formula/calculation. It could be optimized for performance w.r.t. Graph traversal. Further, you might want to go through Gremlin's Documentation to understand things in detail.
https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki

Apart from the Neo4j mailing list, which you're already a member of, you could also raise your queries on Gremlin mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/group/gremlin-users

Comment: Just realised, we badly need a console.neo4j.org with Gremlin support, I'll start working on it towards the end of this week.

Comment: That would be cool Nikhil, contributions are always welcome! Also, better visuals are apprecitated and JavaScript cleanup :)

Answer (score 2):

Not very good with formulae but there are two blog posts on calculating similarity that you may be interested in- you can always tweak it to be more precise as per your formula-

This one uses Gremlin:
http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendation-engines.html

And this uses Cypher:
 http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendations-with.html

Comment: My use case is actually more complex. The formula I mentioned above is perfect for my case. I was hoping I could use only that. Does Cypher not support such kinds of queries ? If not, any other query language that Neo4j supports ??

Comment: It does have the math you need http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-function.html#_mathematical_functions but I'm not very certain that the entire thing can be calculated in a single query. Have to think about this some more

Comment: Thanks Luanne ! Do you have links to any examples using nested Cypher queries ?? Or any other way to split the task into many queries and chain them ?

Comment: Actually take a look at the new cypher features in 1.8M03 like With and Foreach http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html